# Python matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation never makes a second frame iteration

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to use matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation to create a custom animation. However, the FuncAnimation function does not seem to make a second iteration of the animate function. I have enclosed a simple example that I found online, which is supposed to work and draw a sine wave. Both on my computer and the Amazon EC2 server the script calls animate and draws the frame for one iteration. A second iteration never seems to happen. What am I getting wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)


# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    print("animate invoked")
    print(i)
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=np.arange(100), interval=200)

plt.show()
```

Script output:

animate invoked

0

[image]

Comment: The code itself is correct. So I suppose you have a problem with the environment where you're running this. Any more information that you can provide might help understanding why it fails for you.

Comment: To debug animations, I found it useful to run the `animate()` function "by hand" so that any exception encountered is actually show on screen. Instead of creating the FuncAnimation, try running `animate(1)` and look at the output

Comment: I am running in Jupyter Notebook and found the issue based on the answer below. I had not added the to_html5_video() method which seems to be the one running all the iterations. It works perfectly fine now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html), you need to pass an `init_func` to `FunctionAnimation` as well. So you can do:

```
# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# init function
def init():
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    print("animate invoked")
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=np.arange(100), interval=200)

# for jupyter notebook
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: No init function is needed. This is purely optional.

Comment: The init_func is not really necessary, but I found the issue. I had not added the to_html5_video() method which seems to be the one running all the iterations. It works perfectly fine now. Cheers.